# How to set the path to the Lua resource

Tags: lua

i just want to try some lua client and java server, i have seen the question:

[How to get the TCP reply in lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934005/how-to-get-the-tcp-reply-in-lua):

Server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket server = null;
        Socket client = null;
        PrintStream out = null;
        BufferedReader buf = null;
        server = new ServerSocket(8000);
        client = server.accept();
        buf = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(client
                  .getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintStream(
                client.getOutputStream());
        String str = buf.readLine();
        out.println("Echo:"+str);
        System.out.println("HELLO"+str);
        out.close();
        client.close();
    }
};
```

Client:

```
local socket = require("socket")

local host = "127.0.0.1"
local port = 8000
local sock = assert(socket.connect(host, port))
sock:settimeout(10)

print("Press enter after input something:")

local input, recvt, sendt, status
input = io.read()
if #input > 0 then
    assert(sock:send(input .. "\n"))
end
local response, receive_status = sock:receive()
print(response)
```

I cant see how to set the path to the lua api,library/ lua stuff - how do i set it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Lua VM, it's [`package.path`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.path) and [`package.cpath`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.cpath), for Lua packages and C API packages respectively. These get initially set to the `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` environmental variables. Paths are separated with semicolons (`;`)